# Complex MySQL Query to calculate percentage improvement by specific categories

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stumped after countless hours of trial. Albeit i'm not a SQL GURU, so I appeal to those who are. I'd like to know if/how it's possible to write a single query to look like:

```
Specialty              Performance on PreTest Questions

Infectious Disease      25%  (37/148)
Internal Medicine       17%  (2/12)
Pathology               20%  (3/15)
```

This is an Exam database. What I want is a listing by specialty that shows a percentage. The first number represents the total number of people who got a question correct (37). The second is the total number who answered it at all, right or wrong (148)

**Pre-Test Questions**
A pretest consists of a set of modules and questions

```
 module 2 questions (1,2),
 module 3 questions (1,2,3),
 module 4  question (1),
 module 5 question (1),
 module 6 question (1)
```

**Where Clause**
This is part of the where clause. It's how we calculate a "correct" question:

```
(q.type = 'PASS_FAIL' and e.correct = 'T' )
```

Here is the part that derives our total of those who answered it at all:

```
 (q.type = 'PASS_FAIL' )
```

**My Best Attempt**
I'm convinced that we can't do this for the entire set of pre-test questions as one query, so
doing it per-question is ok. I think a parametrized query where we drop in the module and question numbers would be fine.

The best I could come up with is totals by specialty using two separate queries. I couldn't figure out how to make this a single query, nor could I link in the percentage calculation (per specialty). Is it possible????

I am a sponge for knowledge!
-thanks

```
CREATE
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED
VIEW `PretestTotals_M2_Q1_by_specialty_degree`
AS
(select   a.specialty, count( e.question ) as totals_M2_Q1
FROM Exam as e
 JOIN
 Questions as q using(module,question) join Accounts a using (user_id)
 WHERE
   (q.type = 'PASS_FAIL' )
   and 
   (e.module = 2 and e.question = 1)
group  by  a.specialty
```

);

```
CREATE
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED
VIEW `PretestCorrect_M2_Q1_by_specialty_degree`
(select  a.specialty,a.degree, count( e.question  ) as Correct_M2_Q1
FROM Exam as e
 JOIN
 Questions as q using(module,question) join Accounts a using (user_id)
 WHERE
   (q.type = 'PASS_FAIL' and e.correct = 'T' )
   and 
   (e.module = 2 and e.question = 1)
group  by  a.specialty
```

);

**Accounts** Table
[*typical stuff, but I've noted the fields that are critical to this query*]

```
user_id,
degree,   #college degree as selected from a dropdown on a form
specialty #medical specialization
```

**Exam** Table
[*records the result of an online Exam.Their user_id, the module and question number, the attempt counter, their actual answer and the correctness T/F of that answer*]

```
user_id,
module,
question,
attempt,
answer,
correct
```

**Questions** table
[*Records the module number, question number, text of the actual question and the 'type' of question it is. Three possible types (ALWAYS_PASS,PASS_FAIL,POLLING) as enumerations*]

```
module,
question
text,
type
```

Comment: Please put only those information which are needed

Comment: I used to have a lot of faith in the quality of this site, but that fact that nobody has even responded with anything useful, makes be consider that most of you are useless.

Comment: its not the thing ... Your question looks too bulky.. thats why no one has ever interested in it